# Scripted FTP Upload from Container

Tags: server, ftp, upload, containers, filemaker

I am trying to upload a file from a container field to a location on FTP as a serverside script. I have been trying to use the Base Elements BE_FTP_Upload as I'm lead to believe this works on a server script, however I just simply cannot get it to work, I've had the file on FTP, but its always blank missing the content.

I should also add that the BE_Curl_Trace feedback shows successful connection to the FTP, it seems to be my method of moving the file rather than a bad connection. Script attached. (excuse the squiggles, data protection and what not.)[image]

Comment: Debugging server scripts is a pain. You should include the $test variable in the email so that you can check what the plugin returns after the call.

Comment: Try a commit after the Insert from URL step.

Comment: The commit doesnt seem to help! I'm so close, I have this working when running locally perfect, the file exports from the container to FTP with all information inside, its only when I try to adapt to run on the server I have this issue. Is there no problems exportnig containers on the server?

Answer (score 0):

After all of this, simply changing the "filewin:" to "file:" solved my problem, I am now exporting from FM to FTP via a scheduled server script :)

Comment: Right. Didn't see that. I believe I advised you to use the file: scheme in another question. :) In this case it wasn't the FTP that was the problem, rather the empty container. It's important to check each step when debugging server scritps before doing something that relies on the previous data. One neat trick I often use is to write status and errors out to the server log during script execution. Honza came up with this trick which works really well. https://www.24usoftware.com/blog/2011/10/17/debugging-scripts-by-writing-to-event-log/

Comment: Yes thankyou Andreas you have been most helpful in my beginner questions! & thanks so much for the link that sounds super helpful!